# Set Drop Down Value Based on Query String

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, bootstrap-4, query-string

I'm using Bootstrap 4 and CodeIgniter 3.

My page displays a simple dropdown group with various options available. The default value is 'Please Select'. I would like to set the value of the dropdown based on the URL query string.

My HTML is;

```
<div class="input-group">
 <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <a href="#" class="btn dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Please Select</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" value="1">Apple</a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" value="2">Orange</a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" value="3">Pear</a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" value="4">Blue</a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" value="5">Yellow</a>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

My query string is;

```
www.example.com/search/results?coll_id=3
```

So, if `coll_id=3` is in the URL I would like the value `Pear` to be selected in the dropdown on page load.

Do I need to set `$this->input->get(coll_id)` somewhere?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller method, add before `$this->load->view(...);` the below line.

```
$data['coll_id'] = $this->input->get('coll_id');
```

You can set selected item by using PHP ternary operator `?:` and using bootstrap's `active` class.

**View Code:**

```
<div class="input-group">
 <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <a href="#" class="btn dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Please Select</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item <?php echo ($coll_id == "1" ? 'active' : '');?>" value="1">Apple</a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item <?php echo ($coll_id == "2" ? 'active' : '');?>" value="2">Orange</a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item <?php echo ($coll_id == "3" ? 'active' : '');?>" value="3">Pear</a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item <?php echo ($coll_id == "4" ? 'active' : '');?>" value="4">Blue</a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item <?php echo ($coll_id == "5" ? 'active' : '');?>" value="5">Yellow</a>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```